# sql insert into / select from php

Tags: php, email

would it be possible to combine insert into and select from? what im trying to do is for the user to fill out an application the user can fill out as many applications as he or she wants each one is different. at the end of the application the user has to put an email address they need to put the correct email address that they used to log in. if they do not type the correct email address a message will show saying invalid email address he or she will not be able to continue until they get it right. my problem is that the message shows invalid email address but the info is still being uploaded

Insert page :

```
<?php
     require_once("configur.php");
     $mysqli = new mysqli(localhost);

     $query='INSERT INTO profile_table SET email="'.$_POST[email].'", name="'.$_POST[name].'", age="'.$_POST[age].'", status="display"';

     if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) 
        {
          echo "Record updated successfully";
        }
     else
        {
          echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
        }

     $mysqli->close();
 ?>
```

Main Page :

```
<?php 
    require_once("configur.php");
    $mysqli = new mysqli(localhost );
    # check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
        {
            echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
            exit();
        }

    $email=$_POST['email']; 

    $sql = "SELECT * from register_login WHERE  email='$email'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$result->num_rows == 1) 
        {
            echo "<p>Invalid email Address</p>";
        }
    else 
        {
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";
            // do stuffs
        }
?>
```

Comment: `$mysqli = new mysqli(localhost);` it may have connected to your host, but has it [selected the database](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php)?

Comment: i get the email error saying incorrect email address but it still uploads the information with the wrong email adress

Comment: `INSERT INTO profile_table SET email="'.$_POST[email].'", name="'.$_POST[name].'", age="'.$_POST[age].'", status="display"';` You're asking to lose all data in your table here btw. SQL injection

Comment: how can i prevent that

Comment: @Zanderwar How can he lose any data with that? It can only insert new rows, not change any existing rows. Don't tell me about Bobby Tables, he's wrong because mysqli doesn't allow multiple queries separated by `;` unless you use `mysqli_multi_query()`.

Comment: @ghostbaby But you should still learn how to avoid SQL inject, it will prevent other types of errors. See the first link in the **Related** sidebar.

Comment: thank you ill do some changes. how can i fix my problem

Comment: I don't understand your code. Is that supposed to be two different scripts, or one script that inserts and then performs a select right after?

Comment: it should select first and the insert only if the email is correct it should insert

Comment: If the email is already in the table, why would you need to insert it again?

Comment: it will insert it to a different table

Comment: its complicated sorry

Comment: Didn't notice that, sorry. You should reorder the script. Check if the email is valid first. If it's not valid, print the error and exit. If it is valid, perform the insert code.

Comment: can you help me with that?

Comment: @Barmar Is "the first link in the Related sidebar" always going to be the same?

Comment: Uhhh @Barmar, should he not be using a prepared query to prevent sql injection, if `mysqli->query()` is injection safe, why does prepare even exist?

Comment: @Zanderwar I said he should, didn't you see my next comment? SQL injection can cause problems, but not by executing a second query.

Comment: @v7d8dpo4 Not necessarily, although that question tends to be first in lots of MySQL questions. But it was just a comment, it doesn't have to be true forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require_once("configur.php");

$mysqli = new mysqli(localhost );
# check connection

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
    {
        echo "<p>MySQL error no {$mysqli->connect_errno} : {$mysqli->connect_error}</p>";
        exit();
    }

$email=$_POST['email']; 

$sql = "SELECT * from register_login WHERE  email='$email'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows == 0 ) // email id not present
    {
        echo "<p>Invalid email Address</p>";
    }
else 
    {
        $_SESSION['email'] = $email;

        echo "<p>Logged in successfully</p>";

        $query='INSERT INTO profile_table SET email="'.$_POST[email].'", name="'.$_POST[name].'", age="'.$_POST[age].'", status="display"';

       if ($mysqli->query($query) === TRUE) 
       {
               echo "Record updated successfully";
       }
       else
       {
             echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
       }

        $mysqli->close();

    }
```

Your code is confusing me, I am not getting how these two scripts are related I mean is **Main Page**  code calling or including **Insert page**

Still I have one solution for you, you can combine two scripts in a single script like this.

You can use page redirection to call insert file but as you are using same $_POST array ***you should combine both scripts***.

Comment: it was not his fault , it was mine , i edited his code, it was complicated to read , but even so you should know what "insert page" main page mean =)